# how to find out the ip of an ssh HostName

Tags: command-line, ssh, scp

Is there a simple way to retrieve the IP of a `HostName` from an ssh config on the command line? Many times I have to use `scp` and would like to connect to a machine, but I remember only the HostName.

Comment: scp will read your `.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  is there a reason you can't scp by the aliases defined in the config?

Comment: You should add this as an answer. I think when I tried it first, I didn't provide the key or something, so it didn't recognize the host.

Comment: seemed a little light for an answer, but i added it.  along with what I consider to be some interesting ssh config related reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scp will read your `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  as long as you scp to/from the name of one of the host aliases in your ssh config, it should work.

since that seems sort of short to be an answer, here's some more info with things you can do with your ssh config...

Here's a post that describes some of the advanced features of the ssh config file: http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/11/27/advanced-ssh-configuration-and-tunneling-we-dont-need-no-stinking-vpn-software/

Need to tunnel ssh/scp through an http proxy?  no problem, just use the steps outlined here: http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-proxy.php

Another use of the ProxyCommand option: http://jasonmc.wordpress.com/2008/04/16/ssh-magic/

Comment: Short to-the-point answers are great. Otherwise it's easy to go off-topic. Anyone doing tunneling should take a look at [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle).

Answer (score 23):

To map from the `host` argument given on the command line to the ssh_config `hostname` entry is easy using `ssh` itself.

You can ask it to evaluate and print out what it would use for the configuration for a command line, without actually connecting. Then you simply need to pull out what it lists for `hostname` (Note that it canonicalizes configuration key names by converting them to lower case). A simple example is:

```
ssh -G database | awk '/^hostname / { print $2 }'
```

If .ssh/config contains:

```
Host database
Hostname database.example.com
```

This will print out `database.example.com`.

To ping it, you can of course evaluate the output and use it as an argument:

```
ping $(ssh -G database | awk '/^hostname / { print $2 }')
```

Comment: that's the stuff.  great answer!

Answer (score 3):

[There's no need to do that for `scp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25661), but you can use `ssh`'s debugging traces.

```
ssh -v HostName ' ' 2>&1 | grep '^debug1: Connecting to'
```

Answer (score 1):

use a bogus ProxyCommand ...

```
$ ssh -o 'ProxyCommand echo %h>&2' mYaLiAs 2>&1 | fgrep -v ssh_exchange_id |  read actual
$ echo $actual
192.168.1.234
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can do `host HostName` and you'll get the IP address.

If `host` isn't installed (it should be), you can use `nslookup HostName 8.8.8.8` which will use the Google DNS servers to do the lookup.

To do these things, either your machine's resolver has to have a correct config (in file /etc/resolv.conf and maybe /etc/nsswitch.conf) or you have to use a "fully qualified domain name", complete with host, domaiin, and "TLD" (.org, .com, .net that sort of suffix).

Comment: This doesn't look up host aliases in `~/.ssh/config`, which I understand to be the point of this question.

Comment: Haha, I just noticed that too. ssh's `HostName` is an arbitrary alias, not a domain name.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34537/discussion-on-answer-by-bruce-ediger-how-to-find-out-the-ip-of-an-ssh-hostname).